# How can I add a stimulus from a Frame to a lifeline of an object in WhiteStarUML?

Tags: uml, sequence-diagram

I want to be able to have a stimulus coming from outside the frame like Move(d) in the following picture, but WhiteStarUML doesnt let me drag a stimulus fro mframe to lifeline.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know that tool, but you can simply add a lifeline representing the source/target for messages. That would be equivalent. The above is a fragment which is used for a lifeline not visible since it's dragged out of it's context. You can make it a separate diagram with that (invisible) lifeline shown.